# JavaFX applied transformations seem to block KeyEvents

Tags: javafx-2

About: I have a panel displaying a map that is constructed out of polygons and lines. To this map I apply transformations and provide a way to walk around (first-person-like) with rotating and moving the map with transformations.

The transformations applied to the map seem to block (or atleast slowdown) KeyEvents from beeing handled. Sometimes the application keeps rotating even if I released the key.

Also I noticed that the rotation transformation has a bigger impact on this effect.

The collision-detection has no effect on this (since its disabled at this point).

Due to the structure of the application I bind centerR to pointerR.

```
centerR.bind(pointerR);
```

Transformations applied:

```
mapElements = new Group();

Scale s = new Scale();
s.xProperty().bind(zoom);
s.yProperty().bind(zoom);
s.setPivotX(panelBounds.getWidth() / 2);
s.setPivotY(panelBounds.getHeight() / 2);

mapElements.getTransforms().add(s);

Translate t = new Translate();
t.xProperty().bind(new SimpleDoubleProperty(panelBounds.getWidth() / 2).subtract(centerX));
t.yProperty().bind(new SimpleDoubleProperty(panelBounds.getHeight() / 2).subtract(centerY));

mapElements.getTransforms().add(t);

Rotate r = new Rotate();
r.angleProperty().bind(centerR.multiply(-1));
r.pivotXProperty().bind(centerX);
r.pivotYProperty().bind(centerY);

mapElements.getTransforms().add(r);
```

KeyListener-Setup:

```
setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println(event);
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP)
            moveForwards = true;
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN)
            moveBackwards = true;
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT)
            rotateLeft = true;
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT)
            rotateRight = true;
    }
});
setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println(event);
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP)
            moveForwards = false;
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN)
            moveBackwards = false;
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT)
            rotateLeft = false;
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT)
            rotateRight = false;
    }
});
```

OnFrame-Rotation:

```
private final double    fps     = 20;
private final KeyFrame  frame   = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000 / fps), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()

{
@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event)
    {
        double movement = ((moveForwards ? 3 : 0) 
                        + (moveBackwards ? -3 : 0))
                        * movementSpeed;

        double rotation = ((rotateLeft ? -3 : 0) 
                        + (rotateRight ? 3 : 0))
                        * rotateSpeed;

        double oldX = pointerX.get();
        double oldY = pointerY.get(); 

        pointerX.set(pointerX.get() 
                    + Math.cos((pointerR.get() - 90) * Math.PI / 180) 
                    * movement);

        pointerY.set(pointerY.get()
                + Math.sin((pointerR.get() - 90) * Math.PI / 180) 
                    * movement);

        if (checkCollisions)
            handleCollision(oldX, oldY, pointerX.get(), pointerY.get());
        pointerR.set(pointerR.get() + rotation);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What node are you calling on setOnKeyPressed on?   Looking at the javadoc for this method:

```
Defines a function to be called when this Node or its child Node 
has input focus and a key has been pressed. The function is called 
only if the event hasn't been already consumed during its capturing
or bubbling phase.
```

Make sure the listener is added to the Scene if it is not already and nothing calls the consume method on the event object.

Comment: Thanks for your answere. I dont think this solves the problem I have is more frequent on larger maps and the problem resolves itself if I remove the rotation-Transformation. Plus the focus should be always on this node or its child-nodes because there are no others currently.